# How Is a Gap Maintained Between the Stators and Rotors in Axial Flux Motors?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, power-electronics

From my limited knowledge, the closer two magnets are together, the stronger the attraction and repulsion force. I'd assume that would mean a motor designer would want the stator and rotors as close as possible.

If this is the case, how are the motors designed to avoid the extreme forces from pulling the stator or rotor together, and maybe even deforming the metal supporting the coils of copper wire? Do engineers just put the strongest bearing possible and add enough tolerance for some flexing in the materials? How close can the rotator and stator be before issues arise?

Comment: I think that advanced motor design is a bit beyond the scope of what we can answer here.

Comment: Probably same way as compressors and turbines: very carefully, with lots of attention to balance and at least some testing.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: my only experience with a motor like this was investigation of my old e-bike motor.*

Aren't the forces all in the plane of the rotor? Using the right or left-hand rules (I can never remember which) the flux will be perpendicular to the plane of the disc, the current will be (sort of) radial on the disc and the force will be in the plane of the disc like vectors tangential to the disc.

The pattern will be repeated at even intervals around the disc so there shouldn't be any tendency for a mechanically well balanced rotor to pull off-axis.

All this will change when a gear or pulley is attached to the end of the shaft. The bearings in this case will have to handle a load predominantly on one side of the bearing.